# How to configure Sybase SQLanywhere 16 data source in spring boot?

Tags: sybase, spring-jdbc, sqlanywhere

I want to declare a data source, which is actually a **Sybase SQLAnywhere 16** database. I have done the same for **MY SQL** using **com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource** which implements **javax.sql.Datasource** interface.

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:db.properties")
public class DbConfig {

  @Autowired
  private Environment env;
  @Bean
  public DataSource getDataSource() {
   try {
     MysqlDataSource mysqlDS = null;
        mysqlDS = new MysqlDataSource();
        mysqlDS.setURL(env.getProperty("MYSQL_DB_URL"));
        mysqlDS.setUser(env.getProperty("MYSQL_DB_USERNAME"));
        mysqlDS.setPassword(env.getProperty("MYSQL_DB_PASSWORD"));
      } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return mysqlDS;
  }
 }
```

I want to know that. for **Sybase SQLAnywhere16** which jar is required and how to configure the same like the above code. This data source is actually required to implement the below code.

```
 @Override
 protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

    auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource)......
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I have done it by the following code.

```
 @Bean
 public DataSource getDataSource() {
  SybDataSource mysqlDS = new SybDataSource();
  try {
        mysqlDS.setPortNumber(properties.getProperty("db_port"));
        mysqlDS.setServerName(properties.getProperty("db_host"));
        mysqlDS.setUser(properties.getProperty("db_username"));
        mysqlDS.setPassword(properties.getProperty("db_password"));
        mysqlDS.setDatabaseName(properties.getProperty("db_name"));
      }
   catch(Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
   }
   return mysqlDS;
}
```

Comment: You need to have either **jconn4.jar** or need to have **sybase-connector-java-4.0.jar** and need to use **com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybDataSource**  class in both cases.